# VPN Connection Over 3G

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

I have a `PPTP` server running on my linux box, and i can successfully connect an android client to it using `WiFi` but when i try to connect to the server using `data-connection` (3G) it fails to connect. 
I have checked with my service provider they have restricted the `VPN` connectivity for the clients, but when i try to connect to a VPN using `Hotspot Shield` + 3G it connects successfully and the public ip is changed ....

My question is what `Hotspot Shield` is doing to connect to vpn so i can connect to my vpn also using the 3G connection...

Regards...

Comment: any guidelines...

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what Hotspot Shield is doing to connect to vpn

The real answer to this is: it does not go through your ISP. Let me elaborate.

Your VPN, to be effective, should allow you to connect from outside your home, and then surf the world having, as IP number, your home number; further, it should encrypt your communications from wherever you are to your home, so that anyone trying to spy on you locally (an airport hotspot, a cafè, your school) will be unable to do so.

You have checked via wifi that the VPN works, but this is only half of the problem: if you are connecting via wifi to your VPN server, it means you are int he same LAN,that is at home, not away from it.

But you stated that

> I have checked with my service provider they have restricted the VPN connectivity for the clients

so there seems to be no way to do this (although you might trying using port 443 instead of your default port, because this is the encrypted port that is least likely to be blocked by ISPs).

Why does Hotspot work? Because you are not connecting to your home (with its ferocious guardian ISP-bulldog), but to their computers, which they made damn sure are not blocked by anyone. In fact, if you check your IP address (via a Website like http://whatismyipaddress.com/) when you are connected to HotSpot, you will see that you have one of their IP addresses, not yours.

So, what can you do? It depends on how dogged your ISP's resistance is. Generally, changing ports is enough to overcome this problem. If this fails, you should try a specific port, **443**, which is generally reserved for secure http: normally, it is not blocked because it is the port through which secure communications to commercial sites (Amazon, your bank, you name it) take place. This is a good shot, but not a fool-proof one, because your ISP may have targeted the protocol of communication (GRE) rather than the port, in which case my best suggestion would be to find a different ISP.

The details on how to change port depend on your OS and on your router (some routers have a button for *GRE passthrough* to allow encrypted communications).

Comment: Does PPTP even use GRE?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, from Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol: *The Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) is a method for implementing virtual private networks. PPTP uses a control channel over TCP and a GRE tunnel operating to encapsulate PPP packets.*

Comment: @MariusMatutiae thanks for your time, when i connected to the VPN server via WiFi i was not on the same LAN, the clients were connected via a different LAN, or you can say diff ISP